# sensu: "previous check command execution in progress"

Tags: opentsdb, sensu

My client-side sensu metric is reporting a WARN and the data is not getting to my OpenTSDB.
It seems to be stuck, but I don't understand what the message is telling me.  Can someone translate?

The command is a ruby script.

In /var/log/sensu/sensu-client.log :

```
{"timestamp":"2014-09-11T16:06:51.928219-0400",
   "level":"warn",
   "message":"previous check command execution in progress",
   "check":{"handler":"metric_store","type":"metric",
            "standalone":true,"command":"...",
            "output_type":"json","auto_tag_host":"yes",
            "interval":60,"description":"description here",
            "subscribers"["system"],
            "name":"foo_metric","issued":1410466011,"executed":1410465882
   }
 }
```

My questions:

1. what does this message mean?
2. what causes this?
3. Does it really mean we are waiting for the same check to run? if so, how do we clear it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. This error means that sensu is (or thinks it is, actually executing this check currently
   https://github.com/sensu/sensu/blob/4c36d2684f2e89a9ce811ca53de10cc2eb98f82b/lib/sensu/client.rb#L115
2. This can be caused by *stacking* checks, that take longer than their interval to run. (60 seconds in this case)
3. You can try to set the "timeout" option in the check definition:
   https://github.com/sensu/sensu/blob/4c36d2684f2e89a9ce811ca53de10cc2eb98f82b/lib/sensu/client.rb#L101

To try to make sensu time out after a while on that check. You could also add internal logic to your check to make it not hang.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had accidentally configured two sensu-client instances to have the same name. I think that caused one of them to always think its checks were already running when in reality they were not. Giving them unique names solved the problem for me.